# Formatting pandas pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm trying to copy a pivot table in excel in python using the pandas `pivot_table` function, I'm having trouble with the output.  Basically, one of my rows is a long string and when outputting to the console I just get summary information.

I have set the following options:

```
pd.set_printoptions(max_rows=200, max_columns=100)
pd.set_option('display.precision',2)
```

Something like this works:

```
df.pivot_table(['xx','yy'], rows=['Page'], cols=['Variant'], aggfunc='sum')
```

but  this doesn't:

```
df.pivot_table(['xx','yy'], rows=['Page','long string'], cols=['Variant'], aggfunc='sum')
```

The former ouputs a pivot table as expected but this is the output for the latter:

```
In [11]: test
Out[11]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 4 entries, (avip, Text Ads on AVIP) to (srp/browse, Search/Browse below results set)
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Control 1         4  non-null values
Control 2         4  non-null values
Test Variant 1    4  non-null values
Test Variant 2    4  non-null values
dtypes: int64(4)
```

here is a simple example

row1       row2                       data

xx         "very long string"          123

yy         "very long string very"      456

zz         "very long string very"      789

when i group by row1 the output is fine, when i group by row1 and row2 is where i have trouble with the output

Comment: Can you put up an example table that you're working with?

Comment: Have you tried saving the pivot table to csv?

Comment: @Marius saving to csv works fine. just trying to figure out if my problem is with me or a pandas limitation

Comment: Your "simple example" is still unclear. It just looks like a bunch of very cryptic, variable-width text.

Comment: @PhillipCloud made it a bit better

Comment: @DerekKrantz can you add the actual statements that work and don't work with the "simple example" that you show above? Is the simple example the DataFrame that you are trying to pivot on? Or...what? Thanks